# Working with xsd:id in C# web service

Tags: c#, java, xsd

I have a WSDL that defines a field that is type `xsd:id`. I found that wsdl.exe treats it as `string` and everything works fine with a Silverlight client VS ASP.NET Web Service. IDs, in fact, are generated by DB as auto incrementing integers and cast to string when put into SOAP.

With Java, xsd:ID is `org.apache.axis.types.ID` and integers don't work anymore. I tried to find the correct definition and examples of the xsd:ID type but fund nothing.

Where can I find examples of legal and illegal values for this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a definition of the xsd:id field:

http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_ID.html

xsd:id is a restriction over an NCName which in turn is a restriction over a Name. If you take a look at the invalid values for a Name you will see that a name can't start with a number. 
So, an id, being a restriction over a Name, can not start with a number too.
In this case I guess that Java is right not accepting integers.
As stated in the linked page an id must match this regular expression: [\i-[:]][\c-[:]]*

Comment: That regex seems strange to me. I tried to ask regex-explain to explain it but it finds that \i is an invalid escape (and in fact I don't remember any \i character class). Can I just use IDs like "id1" "id2" etc?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html
\i Matches any character that may be the first character of an XML name, i.e. [_:A-Za-z]
So yes, you should be able to use "id1", "id2" etc.